# How to add new users to TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I have installed Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 on Windows 7 Professional edition.

How can I manage (add) new users which can use the TFS 2010?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you don't have a **server version of windows**, you can't have a domain, so you can't add domain users to your project.

You should either **install a server** (which most people might recommend) or you can save your time and effort and just simply **create local users** on your TFS server (which can have any version of windows). This method will work just the same as installing a windows server. To do that just go to this location:

```
"Computer Management" -> "Local Users and Groups" -> Users
```

Add any users you want and in order to prevent windows from showing them in the `welcome screen`, double click on each one of them and remove their `member of` data (which is set to `Users` by default)

Then follow Kyberias' instructions.

Comment: I had to [restart the app pool](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fca050bd-70fc-4712-a310-1985295d72bb/windows-groups-tfs-does-not-see-new-users-until-restart?forum=tfsadmin) for these users to become visible within TFS(2012).

Comment: Can't a user from another machine/pc or a Live/MSN Account be added?

Comment: @bjan I haven't tried those options, but I guess managing all credentials in TFS is a better choice.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same challenge. It isn't obvious how this can be done without Visual Studio but here we go... On your TFS 2010 server:

- Go to Team Foundation Server
  Administration Console
- Navigate to your Team Project Collection
- Select Group Membership from the General tab
- Open Project Collection Valid Users. It should include your Team Projects's groups as 
  members.
- Select suitable Team Project group and add your user into that group.

Comment: Makes sense to me. However, entire Add member group is disabled for me. Any ideas?

Comment: @tishma I think your user doesn't have the admin right in TFS Admin Console

Comment: @tishma I found I had to go a couple more levels deep, selecting another sub group like "Contributors"->Properties->Add..., I ended up with about 5 modal dialogs doing this.  I understand the purpose of roles and groups, but this is insane.

Comment: But after these steps, I just cannot find any users on the network, let alone add.

Comment: Thanks for the caveat, @AaronLS -- For tfs2012 via VS2013 I had to go to Overview, the specific collection, then add a new team member, then add by domain/login by using "check name".

Answer (score 6):

1. Connect to a team project in VS2010.
2. In the Team Explorer menu expand your team project.
3. Right click Team Members and select Add Team Member.
4. From here you can add members and assign them permissions based on what they should be allowed to do on the project.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks but there i can add only user from local pc location how can i change location ...i am using win 7  and  TFS is on my pc and on project will work about 6 peoples
I am not connected to domain :(
it is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that there are no TFS users per se. TFS authenticates users against windows which runs it. Once you have some windows users, then you must configure permissions as mentioned by Kyberias.

Comment: Sorry to say it, but instead of answering the question this response attempts to transform the question into something else. It's a console where you can add users. This is like me saying that there are no users per se, just people who sit at their desk and stare at a screen. :) The reason I'm here is because I also can't add  a user, because the "Add" button is grayed out. I'm already an admin on the box or I wouldn't be in the tool.