# When I install TFS 2010 what is the standard user name and password at /tfs?

Tags: tfs

I just installed TFS 2010.  When I go to machine-name:8080/tfs on my web browser it asks for a user name and password.  What is the standard user name and password?  How do I set this?

Answer (score 6):

It should accept all username/password combinations which are valid on the machine running TFS.
There is no default password thing. (could be that default installation only allows administrative login)

See MSDN for further information on configuring TFS 2010:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252477.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In My case it was all about firewall configuration, let me tell you what I was dealing with:

I checked out windows firewall and I saw that there was an exception for TFS But it was not enough, why? See following image:

[As you can see, TFS has been excepted but not for Public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDPlc.png)

So you can tick the check box for Public or you can change your network location from Public to Home or Work, go to: Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center
[Change Your network Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYd6s.png)
Now you can simply use those Windows accounts you have and it will be accepted definitely.

Overview: What was default Username and Password again?

Assumption: You are using TFS in local network, Your own server your own client!

Short answer: As a simplest method, you should create a windows account, introduce it in TFS to grant permissions, then you can login by that account from wherever in your local network.

Long Answer:

Step1: Create one or more windows account(s), to do that, go to control panel -> User accounts -> manage another account (Create another account while you can use the account you already have) -> Create a new account ->Give it a name

- Probably you may need to select administrator

Then select created account -> Create a password

Step 2:

Go to Web Portal for VS TFS 2015, click on team members (or click on the gear icon in the above bar, and go to security tab) Add -> Add windows user or group -> Browse for account you already created or simply type it to add it.

Step 3:

Go to web portal for Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015, through web browser by some address like http://user-pc:8080/tfs (which you can find it in your VS or TFS) just like [image: this]

then you encounter a dialog box which asks you for username and password, give the credential it asks based on windows account you have created, if everything is OK and no problem with firewall it's done.

Finally:

You might see multiple users in windows welcome screen which seems annoying, to prevent windows from showing them in the welcome screen 
Go to Computer -> Manage -> Local Users and Groups -> Users
double click on each one of them and remove their member of data (which is set to Users by default)
Thanks to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057164/how-to-add-new-users-to-tfs-2010)

Answer (score 1):

There is none. Log in as admin on the machine. Then create a new project group etc. Define admins there (Domain integrated). Their usernames / paswords will work then.