# Team Foundation server configuration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm trying to configure Visual Studio 2010 with team foundation server.

I'm getting following screen [image]

I can add only windows users into user groups

[image]

Now, I need to create windows user for every remote user or is there any way get it work? 
How can I give access permissions to remote users?

Comment: Can you give us some more information on what your trying to achieve? Normally you would allow a group of users access to TFS not on a per user basis (from maintainability point of view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set of users is specifically meant to have root control access to your TFS configuration. Only provide the names of people that need to be admin for your TFS farm.

Regular remote users are configured in the TFS system itself, not here. When a TFS administrator creates a collection he can delegate the administrative rights to another (group of) person(s). These persons can create TFS projects in that collection and assign roles for administrator, contributor or reader at project level.

See [How to add new users to TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057164/how-to-add-new-users-to-tfs-2010) for more details.

Comment: "Open Project Collection Valid Users. It should include your Team Projects's groups as members." I don't understand it

Comment: Yes. I installed server. It's ready. I have 1 administrator user. I can't give access permission to other remote developers. Login and pass box appears in their desktop. They can acces only with my windows users name and pass. I don't understand how to configure it. They must use team explorer or any other software or what?

Comment: Make sure you follow these steps first: http://geekswithblogs.net/jehan/archive/2010/06/13/how-to-create-a-new-team-project-collection-in-tfs2010.aspx

Comment: Windows 7 is not an issue. Also running it here at Windows 7. And skip the sharepoint configuration. It is an option, not mandatory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3703/discussion-between-kroonwijk-and-l0rd-devdem0rt)