# TFS Server 2010: Unable to add users

Tags: networking, tfs

In TFS Server 2010, I tried to add new user in the below path of Team Foundation Server Administrator Console

Application Tier-> Administration Console Users -> Add link
In Add user dialog, I couldn't able to find other users which are in the same LAN.
I'm using Windows Vista. All machines are in same workgroup

Comment: Unless you're actually on a domain with an active directory, you won't find any users automatically. Users on computers in workgroups are local to those computers.

Comment: @J.Steen: you should post this as an answer; it seems likely to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're actually on a domain with an Active Directory to control and "host" your users, you won't find any of them automatically. Users on computers in workgroups are local to those computers and have to be entered manually.

One way to manage this is to create accounts on the TFS Server server and then use those accounts as credentials when connecting from the workstations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507.aspx is an article which describes working with TFS in a workgroup environment more closely and in detail.

The question [How to add new users to TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057164/how-to-add-new-users-to-tfs-2010) (and answers) should also be some help in how to add users on your server.

Basically,

> "Computer Management" -> "Local Users and Groups" -> Users

and add your users. Then,

> - Go to Team Foundation Server Administration Console
> - Navigate to your Team Project Collection
> - Select Group Membership from the General tab
> - Open Project Collection Valid Users. It should include your Team Projects's groups as members.
> - Select suitable Team Project group and add your user into that group.

(From the question mentioned above. You should go there and upvote their answers for being good and helpful, too, if this helps you - specifically Bizz' and Kyberias' answers that I quoted here.)

Comment: "One way to manage this is to create accounts on the TFS Server server and then use those accounts as credentials when connecting from the workstations" Can you guide me to create accounts on TFS server

Comment: I've updated my answer after searching and finding a question that resembles yours.

Comment: I could able to see the newly added user 'xxx'. I tried to access url http://121.242.23.8:8080/tfs/web/ using credentials of 'xxx'. but couldn't able to login.