# add button disabled when adding users as contributors of team project

Tags: tfs

I have Visual studio 2010 installed on windows7 machine, also i have recently installed TFS2012 on same machine.
After installation of TFS2012 i am facing issues like first i was not able to create team project through Team explorer IDE of Visual studio 2010.
I searched on internet and found that i need to install either VS2012 SP1 or Team Explorer2012 to solve this problem.
After installation of Team Explorer2012 i am able to create new team project.

My Windows7 machine users details :
There is a default System Administrator account,a User named USER1 have system admin and TFS admin rights and one more user USER2 not having Administrator rights.

I am able to create new team project\adding project to source control, any type of administrator task with user USER1.

My problem is that i am not able to add user of [PROJECTNAME\CONTRIBUTORS], I performed the following steps :
In Team explorer Team Project Settings -> Group Memberships -> [PROJECTNAME\CONTRIBUTORS] ->Properties
Now in current opened window Add button is disabled, so cause in failing of adding a add user to this group.
Actually, i want to assign rights to another user USER2 as contributors to team project.

Scenario that i want is like :
User1 : is able to create team project and have all administrator right of team project.
User2 : should be able to checkin/checkout any file of team project

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running TFS from Windows 7 and not a Windows Server OS then you will have to add local users in order for them to access TFS. This is because you are working from a workgroup and not a domain.

[Managing Team Foundation Server in a Workgroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Here is a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057164/how-to-add-new-users-to-tfs-2010) that will help as well.

As a side note, there is a tool on codeplex that can help you assign permissions to users or groups and makes managing permissions very easy.

[Team Foundation Server Administration Tool](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i am trying to use power tool for this purpose, if will get any success will update here.

Comment: i used TFS administrator tool to manage users and their permissions. By using this administrator tool now i am able to add users to team project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made permission changes since you started Visual Studio, I would highly recommend that you restart Visual Studio. Team Explorer frequently "freaks out" when permission changes in TFS are executed and starts denying you access to things you actually have permission to. If USER1 is a TFS admin then there is no reason that you shouldn't be able to manage users from Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.As per your reply i closed the visual studio and ran it as administrator, facing the same issue. Now i am trying to use power tool for this purpose, if will get any success will update here.

Comment: i used TFS administrator tool to manage users and their permissions. By using this administrator tool now i am able to add users to team project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to deal with the problem of adding users. This works without the TFS administration tool.

First create a new group (e.g. "TFS Users") in the administration console. Then you will be able to assign any users to this group.

Now move to a team project and go to security settings. You can now see all the users that have been assigned and set permissions to them.