# how to add user in tfs 2015?

Tags: tfs

I just installed tfs 2015. I made all steps this --> 
http://bendayblog.blob.core.windows.net/wp-public/2015/08/benday-tfs2015-install-guide-v1.0.pdf

Now we have 6 members group. What can we do? How to add new user to tfs 2015 ??

In addition, I look that --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb558971.aspx

This site says that you add windows users. What does it mean Windows user? How do I this??

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see, you can add windows user or windows group in TFS. TFS use the authentication with windows user/domain user to access the server. TFS can't create users directly. There are no TFS users.  For TFS group you can add some users in a group to meet required permissions.

[Windows user](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-user-account#1TC=windows-7) just mean the user account to access windows. Suggest to use the domain user in TFS. [Windows user group](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/user-groups#1TC=windows-7) is a collection of user accounts that all have the same security rights. User groups are also sometimes referred to as security groups.

A similar question [How to add new users to TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057164/how-to-add-new-users-to-tfs-2010) for you reference.